# Can I visit Canada without a Canadian visa if I have both the USA B-1/B-2 and F-1 visa?

Tags: visas, canada, thai-citizens

I am planning to visit Canada in two weeks. I am a Thai passport holder with a USA B-1/B-2 visa and an F1 student visa. The last time I entered the US I used the F-1 visa.

Would I require a Canadian visa to visit if I am driving from USA to Canada?

Comment: Canada and the United States are seperate and distinct countries. Does a Thai visa work in Cambodia or Laos?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Well, France and Austria are separate and distinct countries, but a "French visa" (Schengen) does "work" in Austria...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I don't know about Thai visas in Cambodia, but I do know that a US green card works in lieu of a visa to enter Canada.

Comment: A visa to the US does not entitle you entry into Canada. Its that simple.

Answer (score 8):

Your US immigration status is irrelevant unless you are a permanent resident.  Since you are not, you need a visa.

You can check this for yourself at http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp.